# login attempt failed server 2012 r2 rdp

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I've just introduced 2 new 2012 r2 DCs into an existing domain with a view to decommissioning 2 2008 r2 DCs once everything is transferred over. Its a very small company with little in the way of onsite technical help. I do most of my admin from home over a VPN, then remote desktop to the DCs. I've used RRAS on a 2008 server to create the VPN with the appropriate ports forwarded to it by the external router. All works fine.

I've set up RRAS on a 2012 machine and it creates the VPN OK. Remote desktop to the DC goes to the logon screen, but then I get logon attempt failed. If I switch back to the 2008 machine as the RRAS server I can log on to the new DCs OK, suggesting that the RRAS server is the cause of the issue. The VPN establishes obviously, as I can get to the logon screen of the new DCs.

I'd be grateful for any ideas, thanks

Comment: Are you using the RRAS as an RDS gateway or purely as a VPN server?

Comment: logon attempt failed but what error message?

Comment: Just VPN. The error message is just the standard logon screen telling me my logon has failed. I've tried with different accounts to no effect. If I use a 2008 server as the VPN server I can log on to any machine in the domain. If  I use a 2012 server as the VPN server I can't log on to any machine using remote desktop because my account is rejected at logon.